# AuthorizeAttribute redirecting to an incorrect url when deployed to a website with a subdomain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, authorize-attribute, cookie-authentication

Normally (on my localhost for example), `[Authorize]` correctly redirects to `LoginPath` specified in the `CookieAuthenticationOptions`.

However, when I deploy to my staging site (`staging.mysite.com`), the authorize redirection seems to misplace part of the url.
In my case, it is going to:

`http://staging/Account.mysite.com/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FAuthorize`

when it should be going to:

`http://staging.mysite.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FAuthorize`

The app is very basic:

```
//Startup.cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddCookie(options =>
   {
       options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
       options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
       options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Unauthorized";
       options.ReturnUrlParameter = "ReturnUrl";
   });

services.AddMvc()

//....

app.UseMvc();
```

My controllers:

```
//HomeController.cs
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Authorize()
    {
        return Ok("You are authorized");
    }
}

//AccountController.cs
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View(new LoginViewModel());
    }
}
```

Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

---

**UPDATE:**

Strangely, if I do the changes below, it works. So it seems the issue is with having the action specified in the route?

```
options.LoginPath = "/Login"; //I removed /Account


[HttpGet("/Login")] //I added the "/Login" template
public IActionResult Login()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

The problem was **not** with asp.net core or my app.

The issue was with a redirect regex we were using in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
options.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Account/Login");
```

Edit
delete it

```
options.LoginPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString("/Account/Login");
```

and add it

```
options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
        {
            OnRedirectToLogin = (context) =>
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("http://staging.mysite.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FAuthorize");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
```

Comment: that should work, but I don't want to have to do that. I'll give you an upvote though!

Answer (score 0):

Did you define route like this?

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

If not add it in RouteConfig.cs.
Or you can define route directly with [Route("route")].